# How can one compose a BFTask from smaller sub-tasks running in series?

Tags: ios, swift, bolts-framework

I'm trying to figure out how one might one go about creating a BFTasks that is composed of smaller sub-tasks. Say for example we've got two tasks: childTaskA & childTaskB like this:

```
func childTaskA() -> BFTask {
    var successful = BFTaskCompletionSource()
    successful.setResult("Result A")
    return successful.task
}

func childTaskB() -> BFTask {
    var successful = BFTaskCompletionSource()
    successful.setResult("Result B")
    return successful.task
}
```

So how can one create a parent task that carries out childTaskA & childTaskB in series and returns an error if either fails?

```
func parentTaskAB() {
// Carry out childTaskA, and 
// Carry out childTaskB
// Return error if either fails 
}
```

Comment: `continueWithTask` is the method you seek.